# Exception Handling in Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to execute a script using multiprocessing. But in case of errors the script is not throwing exception and pulling out of the processing. Is it possible to have an exception thrown and come out of the execution. I am not able to figure out how to do this since I am new to python.

Below is the script I have written :

```
import os 
import sys
import string
import multiprocessing as mp

path=sys.argv[1]

path_tpt=path+'/tpt_script'


""" Multiprocessing module to generate intermediate exports"""



total_tpt_file_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(path_tpt):
    total_tpt_file_list.append(os.path.join(path_tpt,filename))

total_tpt_file_list = list(filter(lambda x:x.endswith('.tpt'), total_tpt_file_list))
total_tpt_file_list = sorted(total_tpt_file_list)
print(total_tpt_file_list) 



def run_sed (file_list):
    x=file_list.rsplit("/", 2)
    y=x[0]
    file_name=x[2]
    print(file_name)
    path_ctl=str(y)+'/ctl_file'
    path_tpt=str(y)+'/tpt_script'
    path_log=str(y)+'/log'
    print("tbuild -f  "+ (file_list) + " -j  "+ 'tpt_chk_$$ '+ '> '+ os.path.join(path_log,file_name).split('.')[0]+'.log 2>>'+ os.path.join(path_log,file_name).split('.')[0]+'.log')
    status=os.system("tbuild -f  "+ (file_list) + " -j  "+ 'tpt_chk_$$ '+ '> '+ os.path.join(path_log,file_name).split('.')[0]+'.log 2>>'+ os.path.join(path_log,file_name).split('.')[0]+'.log')

try:    
    p = mp.Pool(processes=(mp.cpu_count()-1))
    total_file_list = p.map(run_sed,total_tpt_file_list)

finally:
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("done")
```

Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where and what kind of exceptions are thrown in your script that you want to handle? Please be aware that we cannot run your script, and therefore don’t know how it and its auxiliary processes behave.

Answer (score 1):

Python exceptions will be propagated back up, given what I see, I'm guessing you're wanting errors from your `os.system` call to be raised. You'd need to do something like

```
if status != 0: 
    raise Exception("eeek")
```

What I really recommend, rather than using `os.system` is to use `subprocess.check_output` https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output
It will automatically check the status code of the subprocess call and raise any exception with the status code and the output text. So, your code would look something like:

```
    subprocess.check_output(["tbuild", "-f"] + file_list + ["-j", "tpt_chk_$$", ...
```

You may also want to return the output (`return subprocess.check_output...`)

Comment: Will the script exit from execution as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "script"? If a call to `tbuild` fails, it'll be what raises the exception so it'll already have stopped. If you don't catch the exception your python program will stop. Other subprocess calls to `tbuild` should exit when the python program stops I think.

Comment: I am trying to run a multiprocessing script.  I am just concerned , if exiting from the main process will also ensure that the child processes es are also exit-ed

Comment: In my testing, the other processes did not stop. That's a whole separate problem if you want to solve that.